# general connection to a mysql server

Tags: python, mysql, database

Is there a way to make a general connection to a mysql server and not specifically to any one of its databases? I found the following code snippet. The connect method connects to a specific database called `employees`.

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott', password='tiger', host='127.0.0.1', database='employees')

cnx.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You can make the same connection without specifying the database name:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott', password='tiger', host='127.0.0.1')
```

It would be the same as connecting from the terminal using:

> mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u scott -ptiger

Note: 127.0.0.1 is your localhost.

Also, I usually do not store the actual connection information in the script. I would do something more like this (If you can):

```
def CloseConnection(cnxIn, cursorIn):

    cursorIn.close()

    cnxIn.close

    return

user = input('Enter your user name: ')

user = user.strip()

password = getpass.getpass()

host = input('Enter the host name: ')

host = host.strip()

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=user, password=password, host=host)

cursor =  cnx.cursor(buffered=True)

cursor.execute ('select VERSION()')

row = cursor.fetchone()

CloseConnection(cnx, cursor)
```